# Laravel Restclient 500 error in api

Tags: php, android, laravel

I wanted to test an laravel api by connecting it with android studio by asyn task but i'm getting HTTP status code 500

Here is my code in AbcController :

```
public function register_otpsent(Request $req)
{
    // $myclass = new MyClasses();

    //{cardno}, {mobileno}
    $cardno = $req->input('cardno');
    $mobileno = $req->input('mobileno');
    //
    // if(strlen($cardno)==0){
    //   return response()->json("Please enter valid card number !" , 400);
    // }
    $cnt = DB::table('acc_status')->where('cardno','=',$cardno)->count();
    if($cnt==0){
      return response()->json("This card number seems to be wrong !", 400);
    }

    $accid = DB::table('acc_status')->where('cardno','=',$cardno)->first()->accid;

    $pdetails = DB::table('acc_personaldetails')->where('accid','=',$accid)->first();
    if($pdetails->mobileno != $mobileno){
       return response()->json("This mobile number seems to be not registered !", 400);
    }

    $otp = mt_rand(100000, 999999);

    return response()->json($otp, 200);
}
```

Comment: 500 error is because there is an error in your code. Check your logfile to see what the error is. /yourproject/storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: thanks i`ll try it

Comment: Thanks its working ha ha i was wondering for  days how to do it

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Status Code 500 is a server side error (all 5xx are server side)

> https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

There could be a number of things that could be wrong, it should be basic debugging:

1. Does input `cardno` exists in the request? If it doesn't, boom, error
2. Does input `mobileno` exists in the request? If it doesn't, boom, error
3. Do you have `use DB;` on the top of the page? If it doesn't, boom, error
4. Do you have `use Illuminate\Http\Request` on the top of the page? If it doesn't, boom, error

From this piece of code only, I'm guessing it's one of these (assuming the queries are correct and the tables exist). You should try to validate the data you're receiving, otherwise you'll get unexpected results/errors.

To detect this error, you can either:

1. Access your log files, located in projectdir/storage/logs/laravel.log (or depending on your custom configuration)
2. Request it with your browser and make sure you have in your .env file, APP_DEBUG = true, so you can see the error.
3. Wrap the content in a `try-catch` and on the catch, `response()->json($$exception, 200);` and check the error on your android studio end
4. Check with Postman if you want to use POST, PUT, or any other. (that I usually use https://www.getpostman.com/)